# Tricky number regexp with fractional and negative condition

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for regexp to validate numbers includes fractional and negative condition.
As for me tricky part of this regexp is - if number starts from 0, it must be fractional.
so

```
true:
    0.12
    1.5
    53
    -2

false:
    0
    0.
    string
```

Is this possible with regexp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use conditional statements with easy type casting instead. It will be *faster*.

```
if ( parseFloat(n) === n && n !== 0 ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use such regex, if you really need one :

```
var regex = /^-?([1-9][\d.]*\d*|0.[\d]+)$/
```